# Intent-Filters with pathPattern for authority-less URIs

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

When using an intent-filter like this:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
                android:pathPattern="/ipfs/.*"
                android:scheme="fs"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

then pathPattern is ignored for authority-less URI's - so it will even match fs:/foo/bar in this case. Is there any way to match authority-less URI's more specific than only the scheme? Should this considered to be a bug?

Context: https://github.com/ligi/IPFSDroid/issues/5

Comment: I wonder why you just don't add an authority :) Is there a blocker for that?

Comment: @tasomaniac yes - see the issue - have an authority but this is not encouraged by IPFS